# Match function for date matchup

Tags: excel, vba

I create an array "Checkarray()" to collect the A column data in worksheet "Gun Log". After that I create a "For" loop function for the A column data in worksheet "Gun Inventory".

By comparing the data in two worksheets I am trying to use the Match function to locate where there is a data match, and transferring the corresponding date from one worksheet to the other.

No matter how I adjust conditions the date transfer is always "10/1/2018". I don't know where this is from.

If there are several different results matched in one worksheet, which result will the match function give at the end? In the "Gun Log" worksheet for each gun there are several matched results and I suspect that is the cause of the error.

```
Private Sub submitBt_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Long
Dim g As Long

Dim CheckArray() As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Gun Log")
    For c = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim Preserve CheckArray(c - 1)
        CheckArray(c - 1) = .Cells(c, "A").Value
    Next c
End With





        For g = 1 To UBound(CheckArray) Step 1
            If UCase(CheckArray(g)) = UCase(.Cells(i, "A")) Then
                .Cells(i, "E") = Worksheets("Gun Log").Cells(Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1)) + 1, "B").Value
                Debug.Print Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1))
                Debug.Print Worksheets("Gun Log").Cells(Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1)) + 1, "B").Value
            End If
        Next g

    Next i 

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are comparing dates (and not times) try casting to Long (`cLng`).  It forces both sides to be integers and normally works.

Comment: @Gareth Hi, thank you for your answer. Are you suggesting to used cLng to change the format of the date?

Comment: Yes, both when you upload the data to the array (declare it as a long)  and when you compare.  (Incidentally, constantly reDimming your array is very inefficient, especially when you know how big it should be at the outset).

Comment: @Gareth You may misunderstood. The data I put into array are gun's names, so I have to define it as string. If I define it as long it will remind me error.

Comment: Why not just use `CheckArray = .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row,1)).Value)`?  Additionally, you have `End With` but continue to use `.` notation for a `With`-statement.  The only With in your statement is `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Gun Log")` which was ended before the `g` loop.

Comment: @AnctorHu is this all of your code?  On top of that above issue, you have no `For i`, but are displaying a `Next i` to close a loop.  Looks like some of these inconsistencies would make it hard to diagnose a specific issue.

Comment: @Cyril That's not all. For convenience I deleted some codes that are not related to my issue so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use all the arguments of `Match()` so that you can ensure you have an **exact** match.

You might be matching partially, which is why you only have one output.  You used:

```
Worksheets("Gun Log").Cells(Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1)) + 1, "B").Value
'AND
Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1))
```

The third argument for match is if it should be an exact match, so try:

```
Worksheets("Gun Log").Cells(Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1), 0) + 1, "B").Value
'AND
Application.Match(CheckArray(g), .Columns(1), 0)
```

That "0" I added (third argument) means you need an exact match.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried but the results still remainds 10/1/2018 for some reason.